# C++ Passing a string into a constructor just passes "" unless explicitly modified

Tags: c++

I have this class people

```
class people {
    public:
        string name;
        int balance;
        people(string name, int newb) {
            name = name;
            balance = newb;
        }
};
```

I thought I had a decent understanding of constructors until I couldn't figure out why this wouldn't work:

```
for(int i=0; i<users; i++) {
    fin>>temp_name; // !!!!!
    givers_list.push_back(temp_name, 0);
}
```

No error, only when I'm debugging I have a vector of users that all have names = "" and balance = 0; I am also 100% sure that temp_name is a string like "David"

Only when I make a temporary object, "cat", construct it, modify it's name, and then push_back does it work right:

```
for(int i=0; i<users; i++) {
    fin>>temp_name; // !!!!!
    people cat = people(temp_name, 0);
    cat.name = temp_name;
    givers_list.push_back(cat);
}
```

Why didn't it work the first time? I've checked SO and C++ forums and I believe they did what I did. Curiously, I'm sure the issue is regarding a string because when I say `givers_list.push_back(people(temp_name, 50));`, then the object would correctly have 50 as a balance (name is still "").

My background started with C++ and I've done Java for a long time but returning to C++ is a little alien. Sorry if this is a stupid mistake. I already finished and submitted the program I just don't know why the constructor doesn't work without a stent.

Let me know if this replicates for you.

Comment: Just curious, what compiler you using? g++?

Comment: @RyanFung No, I don't think g++. Aside from that honestly all I know is my IDE Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: @Lorehead  I think it's at the very top in the class

Comment: @Script Kitty Whoops, you’re right.  I see it now.  And the `name = name` problem.  I’ll upvote.

Comment: Many people adopt the convention of using a prefix or suffix to denote member variables, e.g. `name_`: then the constructor can say `name_ = name;` with no identifier clash (or even better `: name_(name)` as Mankarse explains), and it's easier to tell as you look over a function which identifiers refer to members.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your constructor is incorrect.

Inside:

```
people(string name, int newb) {
    name = name;
    balance = newb;
}
```

`name` refers to the parameter `name`, not the class data member `name`.

To fix this, either qualify `name` with `this`, or directly construct name and balance, rather than default-constructing them and then assigning to them:

```
//Option 1:
people(string name, int newb) {
    this->name = name;
    balance = newb;
}
//Option 2: Preferred; avoids duplicate initialisation.
people(string name, int newb) :
 name(name), balance(newb)
{
}

//Option 3: Optimal; avoids unnecessary copies.
people(string name, int newb) :
 name(std::move(name)), balance(newb)
{
}
```

Comment: This is better than my answer as it shows other (better) options.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
name = name;
```

The compiler is using the parameter `name` for each part of this statement. This means it is assigning the parameter `name` to itself.

Change it to

```
this->name = name;
```

Comment: I'm stupid. At first I used `this.name = name` but it kept giving me an error so I thought it was a C++ thing.